# IsolatedStorage browser for Windows 8.1/10 apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10

For Windows Phone 8.1 development we have this nice tool - [Windows Phone Power Tools](https://wptools.codeplex.com/) - which allows you to look into app's actual local storage content and get/put files from/to there:
[image]

I wonder is there is anything like this for Windows 8.1 / Windows 10 universal apps development?

Or, may be, there is some simple way to get files from the Windows 8.1 app (apart from writing the code to read the file content and, say, "sharing it out" from there via email or something)?

I've also tried to look into `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps\` folder, but have not found my development app's sub-folder over there.

Comment: I found this link: https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/
I gets referenced on the official https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: @SeaSharp, it seems like this tool also *only* for Wiindows Phone 8.1 devices. The only reason why "Windows 8" was mentioned there is because this tool will only run on "Windows 8 OS" and upper (i.e. no Windows 7 or anything low), but that is not enough, obviously, The power tools I've mentioned in the question could do the same thing for windows phones, but I'm looking for [Windows 8.1 Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211361) app's storage exploration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is in the `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\App.blablabla.YourAppsGuid.blablabla\LocalState` and `...\RoamingState` folder.

Tip #1: This is a hidden folder, so if you don't have "Show hidden folders and files" enabled, just enter `%localappdata%\Packages` to quickly get there.

Comment: How can we check this if we running in phone emulator?